# Header not full width resize

Tags: html, css

My header is fine on full screen - but when I resize my browser, the header (and footer) do not span the full page. Does anyone know why this is?

If I set `min-width` to a number, say "960px", this solves the problem, but this makes the page super long, for a small browser.

```css
.header {
background-color: #0d0d0d;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-color: #e1e1d0;
border-opacity: 0.8;
min-width: 100%;
}

.header img {
margin: 20px 10px;
}

.header ul {
padding: 10px 0;
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
}

.header li {
font-size: 15px;
margin: 35px;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/66ceGOS.png?1" alt="TS Logo" style="width:75px;height:75px;">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">Public Artwork</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Installation & Exhibition Work</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="#about">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of CSS Reset CSS? Is this on all browsers or just one (for example, just Chrome, or occurs on Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.)?

Comment: Have you tried `width: auto`?

Comment: Your current code seems to be spanning fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/121/

Comment: Yeah, it looks okay there, but with the rest of the content, the problem occurs: http://s33.postimg.org/twht0rb73/Untitled_4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Can you add before min-width:

```
width: 100%;
```